# Execute scripts and Java programs from apache/PHP

Tags: bash, permissions, apache2, java, scripts

I'm trying to allow apache and PHP to execute a script I have written that is located in /usr/local/lib

the script in question is called "pathy" has been added to the path in my .profile, and I can execute it from anywhere. The script is just to simplify the launching of a java program and contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

java Pathy $*
```

php returns `sh: 1: pathy: not found` when i call `pathy test.pathy` with the backtick operator. If i fully type the name `/usr/local/lib/pathy test.pathy` it works and runs the script but gives me a java error: `Error: Could not find or load main class Pathy`

I assume this is either related to my file permissions, PATH or CLASSPATH. But having very little experience with linux, I have no idea where to begin trying to sort this. owing to the "not found" response I'm assuming this is a PATH or CLASSPATH error, but when answering could you also mention permission setting as once the PATH is set that will likely be the next hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my classpath. A friend told me about the -cp flag that could be used to define the classpath. once that was in, the JVM found main().

however now i've just got to find out why it can't find the file i'm passing in for main to work on.